# How to use CallWindowProc in VBA x64?

Tags: vba, api, winapi

I would like an aid in using the API's SetWindowLongPtrW and CallWindowProc.

I am inserting menus in a form and with that, I need to install a procedure in the window to address the functions of the menus.

There is already an example on the internet for x32 that works well, but on x64 it doesn't. I have already made all possible corrections for the correct operation in x64 such as using LongPtr, and also functions with LongPtr when available.

The form is open, however, the performance is horrible, it locks the screen too much for anything. I also noticed that the Title of the VBA window updates frantically. below follows the code snippet.

Remembering that the menu creation functions work perfectly. When I comment on the SetWindowLongPtr function, everything works normal, except calls to VBA procedures.

```
*** Inside Form Module ***

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    g_hForm = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)

    Call CreateAPIMenu 'This function works perfectly. It add Menu and submenus.

    Call InsertProcedure(g_hForm) 'This Function causes slowing on the window and sometimes, closes excel.


End Sub

*** End Form Module ***

***Standard Module***

Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _

        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrW" ( _

            ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _

            ByVal nIndex As Long, _

            ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcW" ( _

            ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, _

            ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _

            ByVal msg As Long, _

            ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _

            ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Const GWL_WNDPROC = -4

Public Function WinProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _

    ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    On Error Resume Next

    WinProc = CallWindowProc(lOrigWinProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)

End Function

Sub InsertProcedure(myhwnd As LongPtr)

    lOrigWinProc = SetWindowLong(myhwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WinProc)

End Sub
```

Comment: `SetWindowLongPtrW` doesn't take or return a string so it can't be a `W` function. There is no error checking.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` anyway.  Use [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) instead.  See [Safer subclassing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)

Comment: @Mark I tried to change **"SetWindowLongPtrW"** to **"SetWindowLongPtrA"**, but the problem remains.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will read more for subclassing to that i can change my code.

Comment: @Mark There is a [`SetWindowLongPtrW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) function. `SetWindowLongPtr(A|W)` don't deal with strings directly, but the `HWND` passed to them does. An `HWND` can be created with either `CreateWindow(Ex)A` or `CreateWindow(Ex)W`, so `SetWindowLongPtrA` or `SetWindowLongPtrW` need to be used accordingly, depending on what `IsWindowUnicode()` says.  Same with `CallWindowProc(A|W)` and `DefWindowProc(A|W)` even though they don't deal with strings directly, either.

Comment: *the performance is horrible, it locks the screen too much for anything.* Have you added any delay operations in winproc?

Comment: @rem `CreateWindowEx[W|A]` is unrelated here. It's `RegisterClassEx[W|A]` that determines the character set a window class uses.

Comment: @Drake Wu, no, i tried just leave CallWindowProc into winproc too, but without success. Same problem.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, it seems that your `lOrigWinProc` variable is not put globally, and then `CallWindowProc(0, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)`
I fixed it after adding `Dim lOrigWinProc As LongPtr` under `Public Const GWL_WNDPROC = -4`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `lOrigWinProc` is a local variable, `CallWindowProc(lOrigWinProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)` in `WinProc` is equal to `CallWindowProc(0, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)`

After I declare it in the module, it works for me:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrW" ( _
            ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIndex As Long, _
            ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcW" ( _
            ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, _
            ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal msg As Long, _
            ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Const GWL_WNDPROC = -4
Public lOrigWinProc As LongPtr

Public Function WinProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    On Error Resume Next
    WinProc = CallWindowProc(lOrigWinProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function

Sub InsertProcedure(ByVal myhwnd As LongPtr)
    lOrigWinProc = SetWindowLong(myhwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WinProc)
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Or you could also use [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) to sub the class.

Comment: Hi @Caio Silva, did this answer solve your issue? Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions and also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it does help.

Comment: Hi Drake! First of all, I would like to thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I haven't had time to test your suggestion yet.

Comment: @CaioSilva Never mind, and also feel free to give the feedback after you have done the test.

Comment: @ Drake Wu I declared OrigWinProc at the top of the module and with Public, but the problem persists. Sorry for the delay in responding, I was busy with other projects and I was unable to test your suggestion.

Comment: *but the problem persists*, did the form freeze? I can move or close the form with no delay. See the result of my test.

Comment: Drake, I tried without the menu bar and it worked perfectly, I put the bar back on and ok, but when I click on the bar, the slowness starts again or closes the app. I'll study a little more to find out if I can get a clue.

Comment: Thanks Drake, it worked for me BUT I had to change                                            ByVal msg As Long      to      ByVal msg As LongPtr            in the CallWindowProc declaration